# How to translate the player ignoring rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a unity roguelike and while making doors that translate the player through them i ran into a problem. when the player colides with a door it moves them up/down relative to the players rotation not relative to the world.

i tried transform.translate. the script would be attached to the player and on collision with the door it moves the player and camera.

```
public bool cantransfer = true;
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (cantransfer)
        {
            if(collision.gameObject.name == "DoorDown")
            {
                Camera.main.transform.Translate(0, -14, 0);
                this.gameObject.transform.Translate(0, -3.5f, 0);
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: depends what this code is attached to

Comment: the code is attached to the player

Comment: Could you add a visual reference? What it does right now and what it should look like? You should also @ the person you're talking with, so they get notified.

Comment: Note. Your code is doing exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: Why do you touch the camera when you want something to happen to the player?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 Camera.main.transform.Translate(0, -14, 0,Space.World);
 this.gameObject.transform.Translate(0, -3.5f, 0,Space.World);
```